# How to match value with Regex in angular

Tags: angular

I need to match regex and need to put condition based on result.. What I have tried is

```
var value1="4111111111111111"
    const str="^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$}"
var result=value1.match(str)
console.log(result)
```

Here I am getting value as null..

Comment: Can you please add the content inside `value1` and the excepted result?

Comment: Please tell me more about you Regex. I try '5 2-5' as input value and match `method` work fine.

Comment: your pattern is somthing like that? 4111111111111(111) or 4111111111111111

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```js
var value1="4111111111111111"
var pattern = new RegExp('^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$}');
var result=pattern.test(value1);
console.log(result);
```

This will return either `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0):

If you pattern is somthimg like that: `4111111111111111` or `4111111111111111`

then use this code:

```
const str="^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$";

'4111111111111'.match(str)
'4111111111111111'.match(str)
```